# Django FileFields not uploading (I've gone through the proper steps...)

Tags: django, file-upload, filesystems

I want to enable my users to upload photos.  Because of local development issues (I'm on windows), I've used FileFields for the time being rather than ImageFields.  On my local server, everything was working just fine.  I've also uploaded images remotely in the past, so I know the drill.

For some reason, it's now failing to write the files to the specified directory.  I pulled the directory as a part of my general git pull.  Could that be the issue.

I've done all the following

Model:

```
  class Post_Photo(models.Model):
       post=models.ForeignKey(Post,blank=True,null=True)
       photo=models.FileField(upload_to="post_photos")
```

Settings file:

```
  MEDIA_ROOT = '/path..../public_html/media/'  (tried with and w/o trailing slash)
```

I've changed both the /media and /media/post_photos permissions so that they are writable by apache (www-data).

```
 chgrp www-data post_photos
 chmod g+w post_photos
```

I guess I can try to make it permissions 777.  Has anybody run into this problem?

Comment: can you paste some logs? (from django)

Comment: Can you tell me where I'd find those logs? I'm not receiving any tracebacks (the model saves).  Logging/debugging is an area where I'm really clueless

Comment: either in the console where you launched the server (if it's not run in background) or try in the browser: firebug->Net panel (after sending your file)

Comment: Well in firebug, I'm getting the following error: Failed to load source for: http://example.com/admin/website/post_photo/add/

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but in my apache logs, it keeps telling me that I have a KeyError in <module 'threading'> which is ignored.  I'm not sure if that's relevant but it **seems** to occur each time i save an image

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your `MEDIA_URL`points to `example.com`. Change it to the address of your site.
file `settings.py`, look for:

```
# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

Comment: oh no, my bad on that.  I intentionally changed it to example.com.  My site is not ready for primetime by any stretch